# NATS Based Resolver Integration - How to connect fine

Tags: nestjs, nats.io, nats-streaming-server

I want to use "NATS Based Resolver Integration" from this doc https://docs.nats.io/running-a-nats-service/configuration/securing_nats/auth_intro/jwt/resolver#nats-based-resolver-integration
(to process jwt by node self)

But how the node should be connect to NATS (as resolver) if NATS deployed as clear image in docker and will know only `nats.config`

```
//nats.config (witch mount to docker as volume and fired)

debug: true
port: 4222
monitor_port: 8222

# Operator named MyOperator
operator: /*operator_jwt*/
# System Account named MyAccount
system_account: ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ55GLMC5TGDAKP56AYY7NIZKDV4AXV7

resolver {
    type: full
    dir: './jwt'
    allow_delete: false
    interval: "2m"
}

resolver_preload: {
    ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ55GLMC5TGDAKP56AYY7NIZKDV4AXV7: /*account_jwt*/,
}

cluster {
  name: "my_c"
  port: 6222
}

websocket:{
    port:8080
    no_tls:true
}
```

the server try to connect as:

```
//nestjs app.module.ts (equivalent of import { connect } from "nats")

@Module({
  imports: [
    ClientsModule.register([
      {
        name: 'NATS',
        transport: Transport.NATS,
        options: {
          servers: [process.env.NATS],
          authenticator: jwtAuthenticator(user_jwt_issued_by_resolver_preloaded_account),
            // credsAuthenticator(new TextEncoder().encode(creds)),
          name: 'service-subscriber',
          debug: true,
          verbose: true,}
      },
    ]),
    //...
  ],
  //...
})
```

but so the server has
`NatsError: 'Authorization Violation'`

and the details view of NATS docker container logs:

```
[1] 2023/07/20 09:58:39.065386 [DBG] 172.17.0.1:33242 - cid:9 - Client connection created
[1] 2023/07/20 09:58:39.077356 [DBG] 172.17.0.1:33242 - cid:9 - "v2.12.1:nats.js:service-subscriber" - User JWT not valid: not user claim
[1] 2023/07/20 09:58:39.077406 [ERR] 172.17.0.1:33242 - cid:9 - "v2.12.1:nats.js:service-subscriber" - authentication error
[1] 2023/07/20 09:58:39.077446 [DBG] 172.17.0.1:33242 - cid:9 - "v2.12.1:nats.js:service-subscriber" - Client connection closed: Authentication Failure
```

What should I do to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

jwtAuthenticator was not enough use credsAuthenticator with creds file:

```
authenticator: credsAuthenticator(new TextEncoder().encode(user_CREDS_issued_by_resolver_preloaded_account))
```

creds file created by nsc tool:

```
nsc generate creds -n sys > sys.creds
```

then you can fails on "Bad JSON" error. See issue https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/8055

- there is closed couse of "fixed in 8.1.2"... but not so, and it happens too on

```
  "@nestjs/common": "^9.0.0",
  "@nestjs/core": "^9.0.0",
  "@nestjs/microservices": "^9.3.9"
```

The reason of error is that NATS resolver will fetch you nest app without body at all. That broke NestJs realisation of deserializer.

- to fix that realy you can add custom to options:

```
deserializer: new CustomDeserializer()
```

CustomSerializer:

```
import {Deserializer} from "@nestjs/microservices";
export class CustomDeserializer implements Deserializer {
    deserialize(value: any, options?: Record<string, any>): any {
        return value.length ? JSON.parse(value.toString()) : {};
    }
}
```

with this NATS will attach your `@MessagePattern('$SYS.REQ.ACCOUNT.*.CLAIMS.LOOKUP', Transport.NATS)async handleClaimsLookup` method

P.S. just need to find format how to responce to that some where aside from official docs of nats or nest.